# Java Exception Handling - is this good practice?

Tags: java, exception

I am working on a Java plugin for a framework.

I have written my code in such a way that entryPoint function looks like below (consider this is the starting point, main function)

```
function entryPoint()
{
   try{
      //some code block
      subFunction1();
      subFunction2();
   }
   catch(Exception e) {}
   catch(IOException ioe) {}
   catch(NullPointerException npe){}
}

function subFunction1() throws IOException
{
    //some code
}

function subFunction2() throws NullPointerException
{
    //some code
}
```

So the idea is, all the sub functions throws specific exceptions to major function and
we catch these exceptions in the major functions and do handling.

Is this way correct? If not please suggest better way.

Comment: Catching `Exception` first won't do anything good at least. But either way, it's too much religion/opinions with exception handling...

Comment: You should never be catching your own NPEs. They indicate a *coding* error, and should be fixed, rather than caught.

Comment: @NilsH: Yeah. i found multiple Stack overflow answers which suggest multiple methodology. But is this approach is not a good design to follow?

Comment: I'd use just one catch block, and if they're third-party plugins I might catch `Throwable` instead of `Exception` (hard to tell without more context and not without risk because some `Error`s are rightfully fatal). You might want to offer a hook function where plugin builders can inspect any exceptions that come by.

Comment: You say this is a plugin for an existing framework. Then you may should implement the same exception handling as in the other plugins.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- The order of the `catch` statements should be changed. Since the first `catch` will match all `Exceptions`, the following two will never be triggered.
- An `NPE` is in most cases unexpected and not recoverable. Catching it implies that the application is able to recover from it and run regardless. Is it really the case?
- Even if the `NPE` is recoverable, it is a better practice to check for `!= null` instead of relying on exceptions for command flow. This is for conceptual reasons (exception-based command flow requires more code, is less readable, the intention is often unclear) as well as for performance reasons.
- All `Exceptions` are swallowed - no logging or rethrowing happens. This way, no one will know if and when something goes wrong because there are no exceptions logged. In most cases, users, other developers and maintainers expect almost all exceptions to be truly exceptional and therefore logged.

Answer (score 1):

Do not catch or throw NullPointerException and Exception's catch block should be the last one

Answer (score 0):

I think this approach is perfect. One should try to handle specific exception rather handling all in one. Putting a try-catch block just for the heck of it is not use of it, but abuse of try-catch thing.

Yeah Exception should be the last one to be handled.Missed this.

In short your intent is good and syntactically you can depend on compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the exception-handling the same way you would do it, if it was no plugin. It depends on you application, if you can handle all exceptions in one major method. If there are case, in which you can continue work, than this could be difficult this way.

The only thing that I would do regarding the plugin-thing is an all surrounding 'catch-all' and maybe some special cases to do some more detail logging. And this also has just to be done, if the framework doesn't do it itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is best to catch an exception at the first possible place where you can actually resolve the resulting problem.

An example:

```java
function int divide(int a, int b) throws DivisionByZeroException {
    if(b == 0){
        throw new DivisionByZeroException();
    }
    return a / b;
}

function int doCalculationsAndStuff(int a, int b) throws DivisionByZeroException {
    int result = divide(a, b);
    ...
    return result; 
}

function void main() {
    try {
        int a = userInput();
        int b = userInput();
        int result = doCalculationsAndStuff(a, b);
        print("result: " + result);
    } catch(DivisionByZeroException e) {
        print("Division by zero happened. But i catched it for you =).");
    }
}
```

It wouldn't make sense to handle the exception in `divide()` or `doCalculationsAndStuff()`. Because what value would you return in case of a division by zero? Nothing, right that's why we throw the exception and handle it in the `main` function where we give the user of our calculator app some feedback.

Now back to your question. If the `entryPoint` function is the first place where you can resolve the problems that occur in your subfunctions than thats a good place to handle them.